# When hovering over element, a copy of the parent JFrame appears inside it

Tags: java, swing, hover, mouselistener

I have the following issue, when I hover over an element (in this case, `JPanel` with a green border), a copy of the `JFrame` appears inside it.

Without hover:

[image]

With hover:

[image]

As you can see, the header and the textbox appeared.

**A little disclaimer, the panel with green border, as smaller size, as displayed on the first image, it was increased on the second image to better display the issue.

This is what I have:

```
package com.system.reservation.airline.panels;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class FooterPanel extends JPanel {
    Color transparent = new Color(1f,0f,0f,0f);

    public FooterPanel(){
        this.setBackground(transparent);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 3));

        CreateAccount_JPanel createAccount_jPanel = new CreateAccount_JPanel();

        this.add(createAccount_jPanel);
    }

    JLabel createAccount = new JLabel("<html><body>Don't have an account?<br>Click here and set one up!</body></html>");

    class CreateAccount_JPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
        public CreateAccount_JPanel(){
            this.setBackground(transparent);
            this.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 100);
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green, 3));

            createAccount.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            createAccount.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
            createAccount.addMouseListener(this);

            this.add(createAccount, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            createAccount.setForeground(Color.red);
            this.setBackground(transparent);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            createAccount.setForeground(Color.black);
            this.setBackground(transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

The desired goal is to get a different colored (red) text when hovering over it.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. (It needs a `main` and to be runnable as compiled.)

Comment: The null layout won't help: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing

Comment: Swing doesn't support backgrounds with transparent colors. If you are going to use 0f as your alpha value then don't set the background and just use `setOpaque( false )`. If you do in fact need non-zero alpha values then follow the suggestions in the provided link.